# Autofac with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm guideline

Tags: wpf, autofac, mvvm-toolkit

Previously I've used Autofac with [MVVMLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight) and the [CommonServiceLocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator) in my WPF application. Now I have a scenario where I cannot use either. So I turn to [Microsoft MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) instead. But I can't see how/where to use Autofac with that. Basically what I would like to have, is an alternative to MVVMLight's "ViewModelLocator" pattern. Have a static class where I build my Autofac container and then instruct MVVM to use that static class to resolve...

For example currently I can do this in app.xaml.cs:

```
<viewmodel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
```

And then in a view I can do like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="SomePath" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>`
```

It might be obvious as the docs say but I can't see how to - any pointers on some sample WFP project would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Autofac is an Inversion of control (IoC) container and the MVVM Toolkit doesn't provide any built-in APIs to facilitate the usage of the Ioc pattern.

There is an example of how to use an IoC of your choice, e.g. Autofac or `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, to register and resolve instances of any class, including view models, in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/ioc?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).